# Can I wrap gcc's atomic built-ins?

Tags: c, gcc, atomic, word-wrap, built-in

If threads are synchronized with Pthread mutexes/spinlocks one can easily wrap the calls to `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()`, for example, using `LD_PRELOAD`. That can be very useful for logging/debugging.

Is it possible to do something similar with the atomic built-ins of gcc, for example `__sync_fetch_and_add`?

I guess that I would not be able to us `LD_PRELOAD`, but perhaps there exists some other mechanism.

Comment: The intrinsics are directly turned into machine instructions. They're not library function calls.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But perhaps gcc provides some compilation flags or other means to wrap such functions.

Comment: Note that the `__sync` builtins are 'legacy'. Consider the more recent [`__atomic`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins) builtins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it is possible, using an instrumentation API like Intel's PIN ([User Guide](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/61206/Pin/html/index.html)). For instance, you can start by instrumenting all instructions which perform atomic updates with `INS_IsAtomicUpdate` and add further exclusion criteria to heuristically locate the instructions generated by `__sync_fetch_and_add`.

Alternatively, you can install a series of NOPs with an `asm volatile` block before each `__sync_fetch_and_add`, look specifically for that instruction sequence, and instrument the machine code that follows (which is bound to be the code generated for `__sync_fetch_and_add`).

Comment: That's a possible solution, but one would need to always run the application on top of Pin. (I like the NOPs sequence trick.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to inject any dependencies on PIN to your application. My main concern is that the NOP blocks might hurt performance, so I'd put them in debug builds only.

Comment: Yes, I see the same issue with NOPs. My concern with Pin is that if you want to have the debugging information in a deployment, you'd need to ship Pin with the application so that it gets executed there. So I'd prefer having a gcc option that allows me to compile the wrapper with the application. Else than that I like the solution.

Comment: Ok, since no other answer appeared, I'll assume one cannot do directly with compiler flags/options. Then this is a good option.